# Output Concatenation of Cell Values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concatenate the cell values that i get from my Code into one single cell instead of writing it in all the cells.

Can you please help me out. Here is the code

```
Public Sub test()

Dim ws As ThisWorkbook
Set ws = ThisWorkbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim lr62, lr210, lr106 As Integer

Row = 2
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


cluster = Sheet2.Cells(2, 1)
Row = 1
For Each lr62 In Sheet1.Range("B2:B700")

If lr62 Like cluster Then

cellvalue = Sheet1.Cells(lr62.Row, 3)
cellvalue = cellvalue & ","
Row = Row + 1

Sheet2.Cells(Row, 8).Value = cellvalue
End If
Next lr62


End Sub
```

Output getting :

```
A
B
C
D
```

output want :

A , B , C , D

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run the `lr62` loop, you execute this line:

```
Row = Row + 1
```

which causes this line:

```
Sheet2.Cells(Row, 8).Value = cellvalue
```

to display the current value of `cellvalue` on a different line.

Remove `Row = Row + 1` and it works as you wanted.